# Difference between "command not found" and "no such file or directory"?

Tags: bash, command-line, executable

For example:

```
$ node
-bash: /usr/local/bin/node: No such file or directory
$ foo
-bash: foo: command not found
```

What's the difference? In both cases, `node` and `foo` are invalid commands, but it seems like Unix just can't find the `node` binary? When uninstalling a program, e.g. `node`, is there a way to clean this up so that I get

```
$ node
-bash: node: command not found
```

**EDIT:**

Results from `type` command:

```
$ type node
node is hashed (/usr/local/bin/node)
$ type foo
-bash: type: foo: not found
```

Comment: Can you update your question with the output of both `type node` and `type foo` (though probably only the first really is helpful).

Comment: @EricRenouf, okay, I did.

Comment: It's probably that 'node' is a symbolic link from /usr/bin/node -> /usr/local/bin/node and the latter is not available hence the error, which would suggest /usr/local/bin/node was deleted after the symbolic link was created.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

That's because `bash` remembered your command location, store it in a [hash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-hash) table.

After you uninstalled `node`, the hash table isn't cleared, `bash` still thinks `node` is at `/usr/local/bin/node`, skipping the `PATH` lookup, and calling `/usr/local/bin/node` directly, using `execve()`. Since when `node` isn't there anymore, `execve()` returns `ENOENT` error, means no such file or directory, `bash` reported that error to you.

In `bash`, you can remove an entry from hash table:

```
hash -d node
```

or remove the entire hash table ([works in all POSIX shell](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/hash.html#tag_20_56)):

```
hash -r
```

Comment: Note that it doesn't have to be `/usr/local/bin/node` that's missing; if that file is a dynamically linked executable, and one of the dependencies is missing, you'll get the same "No such file or directory" message. This can drive you crazy until you try `ldd` on that file.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm but on some Linux distros bash is patched to print more understandable error messages, like `progname: error while loading shared libraries: badLib.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` (or it might be not bash in this particular case, but `ld-linux.so`).

Comment: @Ruslan In my experience you get the "error while loading shared libraries" if it's an "ordinary" shared library that's missing, and the inexplicable "No such file or directory" if it's the *dynamic linker itself* that's missing.  This makes sense when you realize that the former case is detected _by_ the dynamic linker, whereas the latter case is detected by the kernel, and it's much easier for the dynamic linker to print a helpful message (`execve` writing to stderr as a side effect on failure would probably violate POSIX or something)

Comment: @zwol ah, right, that's what some distros (e.g. CentOS) patch bash for. Such patched version then prints errors like `/lib/ld-linux.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory`.

Answer (score -6):

I found on Ubuntu Linux 16.04 that "No such file or directory" means you have to switch your current working directory while "command not found" means you have to use apt-get install xxxyyy_zzz to fix the problem.

Comment: If your cwd has any influence on what will be found or not (unless you prefix it with ./), your PATH is set up in a rather unsafe manner. And a command not being found is not always a problem you want to fix :)